# FileError {code: 6, message: “NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR”}

Tags: android, file, ionic3, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

**I am trying to remove a file from the local storage of my phone device.**
I have given the path and filename and both exist.

I ran **file.checkDir** & **file.checkFile** to confirm whether its getting the path and it returned true.

I tried it on multiple android devices and observed that **its only getting deleted for android versions below 8**. I am not aware of any plugin update for the higher android version if there is any. I tried to google it but there is nowhere mentioned regarding plugin update.

Its throwing this error:

```
FileError {code: 6, message: “NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR”}
```

Although I have mentioned the permissions:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I am not sure about what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks for the help.

```js
this.file.removeFile(path, fileName)
```

Expected - File should be removed from the given path

Actual - File not being removed from the given path

Comment: Let me guess - you target Marshmallow or higer and do not have runtime permissions supported, right?

Comment: i tried to check and request permission at runtime but its showing response GRANTED. i used diagnostic plugin method requestExternalStorageAuthorization().

Comment: I have the same issue, permission is granted but for some photo's I get the error `FileError.NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR`

Answer (score 0):

From sdk21, if Im not mistaken, not enough to specify permission in manifets. You have to request it in runtime and check that you have it any time, when you are going to use it. Smth like that

```
        const val INTERET = Manifest.permission.INTERNET
        const val READ = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        const val WRITE = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        const val LOCATION_COARSE = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        const val LOCATION_FINE = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        const val PHONE = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE

        fun granted(activity: Activity, vararg permission: String): Boolean {
            val list = ArrayList<String>()
            for (s in permission)
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, s) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    list.add(s)
            if (list.isEmpty())
                return true
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, list.toArray(arrayOfNulls<String>(list.size)), 1)
            return false
        }
```

and in code check permission:

```
if(granted(this, READ, WHRITE)
    this.file.removeFile(path, fileName)
else 
    //do smth if you have no permission
```

good for you to react if user denied permission. You can do it in Activity.onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: i tried requesting permission at runtime still not working.

Comment: on asking for permission system should start dialog with asking for it. Do you seen it?

Comment: no it didnt open any dialog for permission. It only asks for permission if its not there but its already there and its returning the response GRANTED.

Comment: I have the same error `NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR` but only for some files. I deleted many photo's but sometimes I get this error 6 in Cordova.